# Double free error on a C++ copy constructor

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a Double free or corruption (fasttop) error on this code.
I think i missed something on the "copy constructor".

```
class Vector{

    int taille;
    int* ptr;

public:
    Vector():taille(0), ptr(NULL){
        ...
    }

    Vector(int n){
        ...
    }

    //The most important one
    Vector(const Vector& source){
        if(source.ptr != NULL){
            taille = source.taille;
            ptr = new int[taille];
            for(int i=0;i<taille;i++) ptr[i]=source.ptr[i];
        }else{
            taille=0;
            ptr=NULL;
        }
        cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
    }

    ~Vector(){
        if(ptr!=NULL) delete ptr;
    }
};
```

And here's the test :

```
int main()
{
    Vector b(5);
    Vector a(b);
    a=Vector(12);
    return 0;
}
```

**The above = operator does not call the copy constructor. Why ?**

It says : "double free or corruption (fasttop)"

Comment: Use `delete[]` with `new[]`. Not `delete`.

Comment: You did also not implement `operator=()`

Comment: You should read about the [rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You will run into problems due to a missing assignment operator.

Comment: The problem isn't really the copy-constructor, but the copy-***assignment***. I suggest you learn about [the rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (of which I personally recommend the last).

Comment: Consider using smart pointers rather than managing memory yourself.

Comment: Don't check for `NULL` before deleting, just delete.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `Vector a(b);` seems like a copy to me.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes you're right, missed that. Updated my comment.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux
I used it.
AND, I still have the problem.

Thanks

Comment: @MohammedAit You are using `delete` which is not the same as `delete[]`.

Comment: You have edited your question, and now it's ambiguous. Is it about the crash and why it happens? Or is it about why assignment isn't the same as copy-construction? Please clarify. And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The copy constructor cout "Copy constructor" on the screen when it's used.
And, I think the = operator should call the copy constructor on this case : 
a=Vector(12);
BUT, I don't see "Copy constructor" message on my screen.

Thanks

Comment: The correct thing to do is avoid `new` and `delete` altogether and use a smart pointer like `unique_ptr`. That said, your user-provided constructor does not set the pointer to NULL so destructor exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndyG "*use a smart pointer like `unique_ptr`*" - in this example, using `std::vector` would make more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the expression

```
a = Vector(12)
```

a few things are happening:

1. First a new *temporary* `Vector` object is created (from `Vector(12)`). This is constructed using the `Vector(int)` constructor.
2. The temporary object is *assigned* to `a`, using `a.operator=(<temporary object>)`.

   The default compiler-generated `operator=` function does a simple member-wise assignment, i.e. it basically does `ptr = other.ptr`. This means you now have *two* objects `ptr` members pointing to the same memory: The temporary object, and `a`.
3. The temporary object is destructed once the assignment is made. This means the memory occupied by that object is passed to `delete` (which *really* should be `delete[]`).

   This of course means that `a.ptr` is no longer pointing to valid memory, and when it later goes out of scope and is destructed you try to `delete` the already deleted memory.

There is *no* copy-construction going on here. It's all copy-assignment. Copy construction is only used on actual construction, when an object is created (temporary or not). I think you're confused because the `=` symbol can be used for copy-construction, as in

```
Vector a = b;  // This is a copy-construction
               // The copy-constructor of `a` is called with
               // a reference to `b` as argument
               // It's equal to `Vector a(b)`
```

This is very different from assignment

```
a = b;  // This is a plain assignment
        // It is equal to `a.operator=(b)`
```

---

The crash is solved by following one of [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

I also recommend you read e.g. [this canonical assignment operator reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Assignment_operator).

Comment: YOU ARE GREAT!
Please, share with me some best books you read on programming. 
I read "Programming for Engineers
A Foundational Approach to Learning C and Matlab"
I like it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a temporary `Vector` in the assignment `a = Vector(12)`, which is being assigned via `operator=` to `a`. The temporary `Vector` gets destroyed at the end of the assignment statement, and `a` gets destroyed at the end of the function. Both point at the same allocated array because you did not  define a copy-assignment `operator=`:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/